# monitoring VM process on stackdriver

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Unix VM process matrix not available on stackdriver

There is a requirement to monitor Unix Vm CPU,memory stroage and critical process and set up alerts on stackdriver.
I have installed stackdriver monitoring agent on my VM which send matrix to stackdriver and I can see he process names when select VM in stackdriver. But can not see the matrix to monitor process while creating alert.

Any help with monitoring process on stackdriver would be helpful

NA

NA

Answer (score 0):

First you would have to install the Stackdriver Monitoring agent:

```
curl -sSO https://dl.google.com/cloudagents/install-monitoring-agent.sh

sudo bash install-monitoring-agent.sh
```

Second, edit the configuration file of the monitoring agent in:

```
/etc/default/stackdriver-agent   #for Ubuntu and Debian

/etc/sysconfig/stackdriver       #for RedHat, CentOS and SUSE
```

Third, restart the agent for the changes to take effect:

```
sudo service stackdriver-agent restart
```

Once completed, create a dashboard in Stackdriver to monitor the process, choosing the following parameters:

```
Resource Type: GCE VM Instance
Metric : Processes
Filter by Name
Value “VM instance name”
```